How to deactivate the internal bluetooth adapter when it's not on lsusb (shows as UART?)
I've tried a bunch of searches, SE questions and even ChatGPT, to no avail. As many before me, I want to get rid of the terrible Mac Mini bluetooth adapter, in favor of a USB dongle (which also includes wifi, but I'm not using its wifi nor is the scope of this question).
However, I cannot for the love of Zeus find how to completely disable that via udev rules (as suggested in this answer), given it does not show / I cannot identify on lsusb or lspci. All I have about it are bluetooth-related details - I even tried writing a blind rule with the MAC address, to no avail.
I also tried looking for tricks in this udev rules guide.
I think I've done it in the past using rfkill, but that doesn't persists through restarts; if it was feasible, I would just pry open the Mac Mini and yank the bluetooth adapter from it. I see Macs don't have an equivalent of a BIOS config utility, so I don't see a way to hardware-toggle it, so I'm trying for a OS-based solution.
Offending internal adapter:
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
    BD Address: 88:66:5A:37:A2:20  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:610965 acl:30613 sco:0 events:1333 errors:0
    TX bytes:10422 acl:130 sco:0 commands:282 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'default'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x1157
    LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x207a
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

After plugging the USB+wifi dongle, hciconfig -a also shows:
hci1:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: E0:E1:A9:33:65:18  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1427 acl:0 sco:0 events:151 errors:0
    TX bytes:25537 acl:0 sco:0 commands:150 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'dongle'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0xab6b
    LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x705c
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)

$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 05ac:8103 Apple, Inc. Headset
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 05ac:8233 Apple, Inc. Apple T2 Controller
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1058:1140 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book Essential (WDBACW)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5744 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 5131:2019  
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 3434:02a0  
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 248a:8566 Maxxter 
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 2109:2815 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 25a4:9311  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 046d:085e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0424:2744 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 248a:5b58 Maxxter USB Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 0bda:b82c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 011: ID 0bc2:2036 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 004 Device 010: ID 2109:0815 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 07)
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x4) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Mass storage controller: Apple Inc. ANS2 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
02:00.1 Non-VGA unclassified device: Apple Inc. T2 Bridge Controller (rev 01)
02:00.2 Non-VGA unclassified device: Apple Inc. T2 Secure Enclave Processor (rev 01)
02:00.3 Multimedia audio controller: Apple Inc. Apple Audio Device (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 20)
04:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader (rev 20)
04:00.2 System peripheral: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 MS Card Reader (rev 20)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015] (rev 06)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
06:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
06:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
08:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
7b:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015] (rev 06)
7c:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
7c:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
7c:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
7c:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
7d:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
7e:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)

/dev/ttySX device details from udevadm info (all the other ttyX show nothing useful):
Device: /dev/ttyS1

  looking at device '/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS1':
    KERNEL=="ttyS1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{port}=="0x2F8"
    ATTR{line}=="1"
    ATTR{console}=="N"
    ATTR{iomem_reg_shift}=="0"
    ATTR{type}=="0"
    ATTR{custom_divisor}=="0"
    ATTR{iomem_base}=="0x0"
    ATTR{close_delay}=="50"
    ATTR{io_type}=="0"
    ATTR{xmit_fifo_size}=="0"
    ATTR{uartclk}=="1843200"
    ATTR{closing_wait}=="3000"
    ATTR{flags}=="0x10000040"
    ATTR{irq}=="3"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/serial8250':
    KERNELS=="serial8250"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="serial8250"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""

---------------------------------------
Device: /dev/ttyS2

  looking at device '/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS2':
    KERNEL=="ttyS2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{closing_wait}=="3000"
    ATTR{custom_divisor}=="0"
    ATTR{iomem_base}=="0x0"
    ATTR{line}=="2"
    ATTR{xmit_fifo_size}=="0"
    ATTR{console}=="N"
    ATTR{io_type}=="0"
    ATTR{uartclk}=="1843200"
    ATTR{flags}=="0x10000040"
    ATTR{irq}=="4"
    ATTR{type}=="0"
    ATTR{iomem_reg_shift}=="0"
    ATTR{close_delay}=="50"
    ATTR{port}=="0x3E8"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/serial8250':
    KERNELS=="serial8250"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="serial8250"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""

---------------------------------------
Device: /dev/ttyS3

  looking at device '/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS3':
    KERNEL=="ttyS3"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{iomem_base}=="0x0"
    ATTR{custom_divisor}=="0"
    ATTR{type}=="0"
    ATTR{iomem_reg_shift}=="0"
    ATTR{xmit_fifo_size}=="0"
    ATTR{close_delay}=="50"
    ATTR{io_type}=="0"
    ATTR{uartclk}=="1843200"
    ATTR{flags}=="0x10000000"
    ATTR{closing_wait}=="3000"
    ATTR{console}=="N"
    ATTR{irq}=="3"
    ATTR{port}=="0x2E8"
    ATTR{line}=="3"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/serial8250':
    KERNELS=="serial8250"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="serial8250"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""


I have all details for anything else under /dev, but found it way too long to post here.

dmesg output (complete dmesg):
$ sudo dmesg| egrep -i 'blue|firm'

[    0.115568] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.147509] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.188190] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-f0] only partially covers this bridge
[    0.940027] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    6.113273] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.113379] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    6.113380] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.113382] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.113385] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.113388] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.201903] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    6.201907] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    6.201908] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    6.202033] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    6.202034] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    6.202783] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    6.203217] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    6.206316] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    6.207719] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    6.207720] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    6.208790] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    6.575108] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,lanai-HRPN-m-7.7-X0.bin failed with error -2
[    6.575253] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,lanai-HRPN-m-7.7.bin failed with error -2
[    6.575377] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,lanai-HRPN-m.bin failed with error -2
[    6.575394] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,lanai-HRPN.bin failed with error -2
[    6.575405] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,lanai-X0.bin failed with error -2
[    6.615441] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=07 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=07 lmp_subver=8822
[    6.616512] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=2
[    6.616514] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
[    6.617557] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
[    6.617743] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 14, total sz 20270
[    6.929240] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: failed to write update baudrate (-16)
[    6.929253] Bluetooth: hci1: Failed to set baudrate
[    7.090997] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: chip id 123
[    7.092189] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: features 0x0f
[    7.094341] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM4364B0 Maui Olympic GEN (MFG)
[    7.094346] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM (001.000.122) build 0343
[    7.094407] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    7.094412] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
[    7.349414] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4364/3 wl0: Jul 12 2021 19:26:30 version 9.30.464.0.32.5.76 FWID 01-45ccefcd
[    7.360829] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xab6b705c
[    8.398671] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.398674] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.398677] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.296033] tg3 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: No firmware running
[   14.497218] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_p2p_set_firmware: failed to update device address ret -52
[   18.147161] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   18.147166] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   18.147170] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

lsmod output:
$ lsmod

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nf_conntrack_netlink    57344  0
xfrm_user              49152  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
br_netfilter           32768  0
rfcomm                 90112  32
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  8
xt_conntrack           16384  6
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              20480  9
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_nat           16384  1
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 53248  3 ip6table_nat,iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack          176128  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
nf_tables             253952  0
nfnetlink              16384  3 nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             32768  3 ip6table_filter,ip6table_nat,ip6table_mangle
iptable_filter         16384  1
tun                    61440  1
bridge                299008  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
cmac                   16384  25
overlay               151552  0
algif_hash             16384  12
algif_skcipher         16384  12
af_alg                 32768  50 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   106496  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_intel        45056  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_cadence      40960  1 soundwire_intel
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
cdc_mbim               20480  0
snd_sof_pci            20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
cdc_wdm                28672  1 cdc_mbim
snd_sof               147456  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
soundwire_bus          90112  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
cdc_ncm                45056  1 cdc_mbim
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_sof
cdc_ether              24576  1 cdc_ncm
usbnet                 53248  3 cdc_mbim,cdc_ncm,cdc_ether
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
snd_soc_skl           184320  0
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    57344  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
btusb                  65536  0
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          339968  5 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
coretemp               20480  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
kvm_intel             335872  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_intel          57344  2
nls_cp437              20480  1
kvm                  1032192  1 kvm_intel
uvcvideo              118784  0
brcmfmac              450560  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
vfat                   20480  1
intel_spi_pci          16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
brcmutil               24576  1 brcmfmac
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
intel_spi              24576  1 intel_spi_pci
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
fat                    86016  1 vfat
fuse                  163840  7
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
rapl                   16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_codec         167936  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
spi_nor               102400  1 intel_spi
snd_usb_audio         352256  1
intel_cstate           20480  0
videobuf2_common       69632  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
cfg80211             1040384  1 brcmfmac
mtd                    81920  2 spi_nor,intel_spi
ee1004                 20480  0
snd_hda_core          106496  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
8250_dw                20480  0
intel_uncore          204800  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        45056  1 snd_usb_audio
videodev              270336  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
mc                     65536  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 28672  0
sg                     40960  0
mousedev               24576  0
hci_uart              159744  0
btqca                  24576  1 hci_uart
mei_me                 45056  1
btrtl                  28672  2 hci_uart,btusb
btbcm                  20480  2 hci_uart,btusb
btintel                40960  2 hci_uart,btusb
mei                   143360  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
bluetooth             733184  70 btrtl,btqca,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
intel_pch_thermal      20480  0
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  7 bluetooth,cfg80211
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
acpi_tad               16384  0
evdev                  20480  57
mac_hid                16384  0
apple_bce              94208  2
snd_pcm               155648  14 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,apple_bce,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_seq_oss            49152  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_oss
snd_rawmidi            45056  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq                86016  6 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  4 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                   114688  24 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_seq_oss,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,apple_bce,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                73728  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  3 iptable_filter,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle
x_tables               53248  14 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,ip6table_nat,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_CHECKSUM,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,iptable_nat,ip6table_mangle,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle
ext4                  917504  3
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  163840  1 ext4
btrfs                1626112  0
blake2b_generic        20480  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              122880  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              16384  4 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs,nf_tables
crc32c_generic         16384  0
ses                    20480  0
enclosure              16384  1 ses
scsi_transport_sas     49152  1 ses
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 65536  0
hid                   151552  2 usbhid,hid_generic
dm_mirror              28672  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
dm_mod                163840  2 dm_log,dm_mirror
uas                    32768  1
usb_storage            81920  2 uas
i915                 3031040  124
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
ttm                    81920  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        307200  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cec                    69632  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
rc_core                65536  2 cec
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  7
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
sdhci_pci              73728  0
drm                   585728  20 drm_kms_helper,i915,ttm
cqhci                  32768  1 sdhci_pci
aesni_intel           380928  37
tg3                   200704  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
sdhci                  81920  1 sdhci_pci
i2c_i801               36864  0
mmc_core              200704  4 sdhci,cqhci,brcmfmac,sdhci_pci
cryptd                 28672  14 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
libphy                159744  1 tg3
xhci_pci               20480  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
intel_lpss_pci         28672  2
thunderbolt           327680  0
xhci_hcd              311296  1 xhci_pci
intel_gtt              24576  1 i915
agpgart                45056  2 intel_gtt,ttm
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  2 intel_lpss_pci,intel_lpss_acpi
idma64                 20480  0


Please edit to include results from terminal for sudo dmesg| egrep -i 'blue|firm'

@Jeremy31 done!

Edit to include results for lsmod hopefully there is a broadcom specific module that can be blacklisted to stop the internal bluetooth from working

Ready  @Jeremy31

Run sudo dmesg| nc termbin.com 9999 Post URL

Do a reboot and then run sudo dmesg| nc termbin.com 9999 and post a new URL

updated, @Jeremy31: https://termbin.com/poe4

I am having no luck trying to find info on how to disable the internal.  Is the problem that it doesn't work but still shows as a bluetooth device?

it's just the worst bluetooth adapter I ever found. Its connection is terrible with my keyboard and mouse at the same table.

Have you tried https://github.com/leifliddy/macbook12-bluetooth-driver

@Jeremy31 yeah... No dice either. The adapter is weak even when I boot to the macOS, I wouldn't say it's a Linux issue.

For a test do echo "blacklist hci_uart"| sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/btest.conf then reboot

There is one thing you can try, with the USB Bluetooth disconnected in terminal do bluetoothctl
power off
quit
Hopefully that will keep the internal off and allow the USB device to work

that doesn't persists through restarts, does it?

Try it and see, let me know

no dice, as expected... :( I edited the original question with the complete dmesg, I only saw your other comment now
